# Add sub categories option is not working in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

when I am going to add new sub categories and clicking on add sub categories only page refresh and new adding option is not showing please help. I am using 1.9.2 magento.

Comment: Please provide more information. Is this a new install? did something suddenly stop working? Has it ever worked?

Comment: ITS NOT NEW INSTALLATION. I AM USING MAGENTO FROM LAST 2 MONTHS ALREADY 300 PRODUCTS ADDED IN MAGENTO. BUT WHEN I AM GOING TO ADD NEW SUB CATEGORIES TODAY ITS NOT WORKING.

Comment: Please post any error messages, have you checked the console in developer tools, have you cleared your cache? Have you checked you logs?

Comment: i have cleared cache and when clicking on add sub categories after few times its showing same page new sub category form is not opening

Comment: POST http://www.duffolo.com/index.php/best24x7/catalog_category/add/key/226ef30066f7d5139d3f802cad2fe741/store/0/parent/0?isAjax=true
404 Not Found

Comment: its showing this error

Comment: Please add new information to your original question instead of adding comments.